# Image file parameter passing at NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method from where I pass a text and image file as a parameter to another function. The text  is passed but the image file is always undefined. What am I missing?

```
    function anotherFunc(text, imageFile){

      if (typeof imageFile == 'undefined'){
        console.log("image undefined")
      } else {
        console.log("Got image")
    }
 }

function theCaller(){
  var text ="hello"
  var imageFile = 'img.png'
  anotherFunc(text, imageFile)
}
```

This always outputs image `undefined` although I have the image in the same directory of the source code. I have also tried `var imageFile = './img.png'` but that does not help either.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more context, since you tagged this `node.js`. When I put the code you provided in CodePen, it works correctly.

Comment: Based on the code which you've provided, this should work. There's got to be something else going on here.

Comment: In your case `imageFile` is just a string, so your `if` condition is just checking to see if the string passed in was equal to the _string_ `"undefined"` (not the actual `undefined` value). In any case, the code you have works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to test imageFile whether it's undefined or not you should do it like:

```
if (typeof imageFile == 'undefined'){
   console.log("image undefined")
  } else {
    console.log("Got image")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only verifying that the string is not "undefined". Besides changing the code to correctly verify if it is undefined by either saying `if (imageFile)` or more explicitly `if (typeof imageFile === 'undefined')` you also need to actually provide an image and not just the text.

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let fileName = 'someName.png';
let fullPath = path.join(__dirname, 'some', 'path', fileName);

if (fs.existsSync(fullPath)) {
  let file = fs.readFileSync(fullPath);
  // do something with the file
}
```